# Drupal Lightbox 2 not displaying image

Tags: javascript

http://www.wmfs.net/blackcountrylevel3plan

I have the Isotope working with Lightbox2, however the Lightbox is just displaying a blank space and not the image.

I am trying different things to troubleshoot the problem, different configurations in Drupal, putting the JS in the header and footer, there are no significant JS errors in Web Inspector.

Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Ant

Answer (score 2):

as i see in the console, you are using jquery.min.js?v=1.9.1

and lightbox.js is giving this error:

> TypeError: $.browser is undefined

because this function has been [remove since 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed)

I'll suggest you to use default jquery version 1.4.2 where $.browser is deperecated but should work or use another ligtbox module like [colorbox](https://drupal.org/project/colorbox)

Comment: I'm using Colorbox now which works, but isn't working on mobile, instead of the JS effect the image is just linking to a larger image.

Comment: Looking for a fix now....